# Cannot boot into LUbuntu after configuring RAID

Tags: partition, raid, lubuntu

I am having some problems trying to get LUbuntu working with RAID 0.
(I am using LUbuntu Alternate 64bit).

My Setup:

- /dev/sda 2.0TB Physical Disk;
- /dev/sdb 2.0TB Physical Disk;
- /dev/sdc 2.0TB Physical Disk;
- /dev/sdd 2.0TB Physical Disk;

I run the installer and opt for the manual partitioning. On each disk, I create a partition:

- 1.99TB "physical volume for RAID"

I then create a software RAID 0 from each of the /dev/sd*1 partitions.
This RAID partition is then set to Ext4, and mount point of "/".

Then on each disk I create another partition:

- 2GB "physical volume for RAID"

I then create a software RAID 0 from each of the /dev/sd*2 partitions.
This RAID partition is then set to "swap" (so 8GB swap for 8GB RAM).

I then create a 1GB Ext4 partition on /dev/sda, and set the mount point of "/boot". (This is partition /dev/sda3).

Once done, I write the partitions to disk.

When I get to the GRUB install screen, I configure it to install to /dev/sda3 and everything seems successful, but on reboot it cannot find the operating system.

Am I doing this all wrong, or is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should also make /boot a mdadm RAID-1, with 1GB partitions on each of the 4 drives (`/dev/sd?3`), so that /boot is still available even if `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sda3` dies.
2. The BIOS does not look for the boot-loader (`grub`) in a partition like /dev/sda3.  It looks for it at the start of the boot drive.  In other words, you should `grub-install` to the disk device (`/dev/sda`), not a partition device (`/dev/sda3`).  With a RAID setup like this, you should `grub-install` to **ALL** of the disk devices, so that they all have the grub boot-loader in the MBR.  If a drive dies, your system will still boot.